# media query is not applying for android screen 720 * 1280 in phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, media-queries

I am developing android apps in phonegap with responsive css. My apps working on all screens fine but media query not applying on 720 * 1280. my is media query like shown below

- @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and
  (max-device-width : 1024px) {}
- @media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 767px) {}
- @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 801px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 515px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 384px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {}
- @media only screen and (max-width : 240px) {}

please tell me if there is need to add extra media screens. I tried lot but not achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's a lot of breakpoints and lots of them are conflicting and mixing with each other, and are redundant. for example this

    "media only screen and (max-width : 384px) {}" conflicts with

   "media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {}" adjust your mediaqueries, the error you experience is probably due to this

Comment: Are you testing on real hardware or in a desktop browser? Many devices have a pixel ratio > 1, and your media query needs to reflect that.

For example, the iPhone 5 screen is 640px wide, but has a pixel ratio of 2, so for the purposes of media queries, it responds to the width of 320px. The same is true for all recent devices with HD screens.

Comment: Also, note that the meaning of width changes between portrait and landscape. You have no media query that applies to a width of 1280px (the biggest is 1024px).